# Build form dynamically in angular2 based on a database driven metadata or json response

Tags: angularjs, json, forms, angular, dynamic

​I want to build a form dynamically based on a `json` response or from a database driven metadata collection/table in **Angular 2**

**Day 1 :** There are 3 fields in the json response object.

```
{ 
"first_name : "John",
"last_name" : "Doe",
"phone" : "88888888"
}
```

**From this response the form looks like this:**

```
First name:  John  
Last Name: Doe  
Phone: 88888888​
```

**Day 5 :** Another field called `email` is added to the json response which looks like this.

```
{ 
"first_name : "john",
"last_name" : "Doe",
"phone" : "88888888",
"email" : "john.doe@angular2.com"
}
```

Is it possible to show the email field in the browser without making any code change in angular 2.

i.e. therefore no test and deploy cycle.
i.e. dynamically build the form based on some form of database driven metadata or build the form based on the json response object.

**The form should look as below:**

```
First name:  John  
Last Name: Doe  
Phone: 88888888​  
Email: john.doe@angular2.com​
```

**Is it possible to achieve in Angular 2?**

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you have a collection of objects. And you want to populate your fields dynamically.

So, an easy way to do that is in the client side, and I'm assuming you are using PHP, you can use something like this:

```
<div ng-init="yourAngularFunction(<?php $objUsed ?>);">
```

And in your Angular controller, something like to create a model:

```
$scope.yourAngularFunction = function(objUsed){
    $scope.objUsed = objUsed;
}
```

And now in your PHP file, you can use, and show all your fields.

```
 First name: {{objUsed.first_name}}
 Last Name: {{objUsed.last_name }}
 ...
```

And you can also use an angular conditions, like **ng-if** to show or not the email field.

Comment: Thanks for your help. we are not using PHP.  Using HTML5 and tBootsrap.  The labels and corresponding field values have to be picked up from the json response object.  I am specifically trying to find out if there is an easy way to do this with Angular 2 new features. hoping you have good working knowledge in Angular Version 2.